# How to add custom subtitle language option swift

Tags: swift, avplayer, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I am facing a problem in the tvOS application. Actually, I have two url, one of video and another one is subtitle url. So I want to give the custom language option in subtitle menu. Please help me. If you have any idea please let me know.

For the understanding. I have attached the image below.

[image]

Comment: I guess that a possible trick could be to download both of the `.m3u8` (as text files). In the first file of the video, edit it (it's sample text with some protocols/tags), and add yourself the info of the subtitles one. Then try to set that edited file as the source of your video. You may have to fake a server to get a "valid" URL (and not a path).

Answer (score 0):

I also have been faced with same task some time ago. If you use `AVPlayerViewController` then there is no official SDK to change `Subtitles` group. `AVPlayerViewController` reads the stream and build the UI based on HLS metadata. You can just change metadata presented in `Info` group. [See link on Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19493) 

Since tvOS 11 you can add new section to menu. [See WWDC2017-209](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/209/)
[image: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/209/]

Comment: $Igor Kotkovets, Do you have some sample code regarding this. And how did you resolved this problem?

Comment: @Sankalap Yaduraj Singh, I didn't solved the problem. No possibility to change `Subtitles` section. `AVPlayer` doesn't allow to load external subtitles file (AVPlayerViewController requires it). AVPlayer  is intended for playing a single media asset at a time See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer

Comment: Hey! Do you get any solution for that